# spring-boot - initializer that runs before DatasourceAutoConfiguration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using `spring-boot`, `spring-boot-test`, `DataSourceAutoConfigration` and `org.testcontainers` for preparing database. In spring test, I want to run `org.testcontainer.mariadb` only in profile `ci` and only Once for whole test suite.

Because I am using @MockBean in 30~40 test classes, `ApplicationContext` is also created 30~40 times. So if I try to use `org.testcontainer` as a bean, that bean would be created many times.

In this situation How can I run org.testcontainer only once in whole test suite and only for profile `ci`?

Or in more abstract form How can I create spring initializer which run in order that I want.

---

I thought I could workaround by launching org.testcontainer in `<cinit>`. but because  is called before Spring comes into play I can't access spring environment for checking profile `ci`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<cinit>` I could make one Initializer that run `org.testcontainer` as singleton. Initializer is called before any AutoConfiguration kicked in, and could access ApplicationContext.